# Covert float into time in a pandas series

Tags: python, date, dataframe

please see the data here: [screenshot from Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBxCP.png)

I am trying to assign the time 19:00 (7pm) for all records of the column "Beginn_Zeit". For now I put the float 19.00. Now I need to convert it to a time format so that I can subsequently merge it with a date of the column "Beginn_Datum". Once I have this merged column, I need to paste its value to a all records with NaT of a different column "Delta2".

```
dfd['Beginn'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Beginn'], dayfirst=True)
dfd['Ende'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Ende'], dayfirst=True)
dfd['Delta2'] = dfd['Ende']-dfd['Beginn']
dfd.Ende.fillna(dfd.Beginn,inplace=True)
dfd['Beginn_Datum'] = dfd['Beginn'].dt.date
dfd["Beginn_Zeit"] = 19.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to better match your updated example.

```
from datetime import time, datetime
dfd['Beginn_Zeit'] = time(19,0)
# create new column combining date and time
new_col = dfd.apply(lambda row: datetime.combine(row['Beginn_Datum'], row['Beginn_Zeit']), axis=1)
# replace null values in Delta2 with new combined dates
dfd.loc[dfd['Delta2'].isnull(), 'Delta2'] = new_col
```

Comment: Thanks Aiguofer for your quick response. Unfortunately, it plots the following fault message.

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

To be more concrete I would need, in the first step, a "Beginn Datum" like this: 2015-11-29 19:00:00 2015-11-29 19:00:00 2015-11-29 19:00:00 2015-11-29 19:00:00 2015-11-29 19:00:00

instead of like this: 2015-11-29 2015-11-29 2015-11-29 2015-11-29 2015-11-29

In the second step, I would need to go through Delta2 and whenever there is a NaT, I would require to copy the value from the new "Beginn_Datum" with the 2015-11-29 19:00:00.

Thanks!

Comment: @JonasRoth hey, I updated the code to better match what you're after. However, this seems a little odd to me since you'll end up with `timedelta` and `datetime` objects in the `Delta2` column... is that really what you're after?

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I sought for! Awesome support, thank you so much!

Comment: @JonasRoth sure thing! welcome to SO :) if the answer solved your problem feel free to upvote and/or accept it.